# How to render the autodesk model in offline mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm making an ios app and have used the forge api to render the model in the webview. I'm using React Native but i'm open to suggestions for objective-c too.

The problem i'm having is to render the model in offline mode. The app could download svf file and save on the phone's disk, but how can i load the file and render that in the webview? I find the A360 app can render the model in offline mode but not sure if it's rendered in webview. I also find the Autodesk.Viewing.FileLoader api, but couldn't figure out with it and i don't find an example. This is what I have tried:

```
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv'));

var filepath = '/Users/zheminzhang/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/901B40DC-1DB6-4596-A24A-6D3FAA1EA5C5/data/Containers/Data/Application/925466F3-A623-416B-81A4-1EB62123AA66/Documents/RNFetchBlob_tmp/RNFetchBlobTmp_d0411119-5006-4529-8734-7e70764a309b.svf';

var options = {
    doc: filepath,
    env: 'Local'
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer (options, function () {
    viewer.start(options.doc, options);
    // viewer.initialize();
    // var fileloader = new Autodesk.Viewing.FileLoader(viewer);
    // fileloader.loadFile(filepath);
});
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Still looking for some answers in regards to this question, it was great meeting you yesterday. Here is something I thought can help with how to approach this issue. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html Like I mentioned, LMV has some capabilities for offline viewing, but still asking which ones and if they are available to 3rd party developers. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to notice this post. I am not sure how useful it would be, just sharing what I have practiced with iOS + Forge Viewer. 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/standalone-app-of-forge-viewer-on-ios-by-cordova

Comment: Thanks Xiaodong, Jaime actually forwarded this link before, and i've gone through it. Our use case is a bit different though, because the model needs to be downloaded when the user is viewing a selected model in online mode, and saved to the device's storage, instead of being placed under the project folder, i.e. root\www\, so the webview might have issue to load the model due to CORS policy. Another major issue to overcome in our use case is to automatically convert the model to an offline package and download to the device local storage and unzip.